# Non-empty validation for ASP.NET form

Tags: asp.net, forms, validation

I want to validate string for e-mail is non-empty string or space. I have tried to put required and the `RegularExpressionValidator` for email but it seems not working.

Comment: Could you please post your code here so we can better see the problem and help you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(thisString)) { 
    //code to execute
}
```